# Find H1 Text Using Bash

Tags: regex, bash

What's regex to find text "This is the title" inside this tags ? Using Grep, Sed or Awk.

Code Example:

```
<h1 class="round title">
  <a href="/somepage">This is the title</a>
</h1>
```

I've tried this on above h1 tag.

```
curl --silent http://domain.com/index.html | grep "<h1 class=\"round title\">"
```

Result is:

```
<h1 class="round title"><a href="/somepage">This is the title</a></h1>
```

and I only need "This is the title" part of it.

Comment: For the general case, you need to use an HTML parser.

Comment: If I needed to use HTML parser, I would. But I need bash =)

Comment: `grep` is completely out of the question here, because it operates on a line at a time. Sed or awk can handle simple cases, but for adequate processing of structured data you really do need to use a tool which can handle the structure. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: I don't know I've seen grep work on multiple lines somehow. Thanks for the link will check it out.

Comment: Yeah the link provided is not helping, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got it with this following command.

```
curl --silent http://domain.com/index.html | grep -E "<h1.*><a.*>(.*?)</a></h1>" | sed 's/.*<a.*>\(.*\)<\/a>.*/\1/'
```

Thank you all.